# How to cut small icons from image and then export with Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-editing

I am having trouble with this. I tried using the magnetic lasso tool to cut an icon inside a big image but i have more icons that i need to cut that have the same size and i dont want to cut them all individually.

Then i need to to put each one on a separate layer so i can export them in singles image. Whats the best way do to that? Each layer must have the same size has de image.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Photoshop use the magnetic lasso tool to copy the first icon, then, open a new window. The default size should be the size of the icon you just copied. Paste it into the new window. Then go back to the original window and move the selection to the next part of the image. Copy the next part. Go back to the second window and create a new layer, then just paste the second icon on top. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: But when i copy and cut to another new file the magnetic lasso selection is gone and i have to use the tool again. What am i doing wrong? :\

Comment: Just read your post carefully and problem solved accepting your answer as the correct one :D